# Solution of ODE with point sounce

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have a two-point boundary value problem

> $$\left(\tau u_{x}\right)_{x}=f(x), \quad 0<x<1, \quad u(0)=0, \quad u(1)=0$$
>
> where $\tau$ is constant, is the surface tension coefficient of a string. We assume $f(x)$ is a unit point force at some point $\alpha$ where $0<\alpha < 1$, so that

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \phi(x) d x=\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{0}^{1} \delta_{\epsilon}(x-\alpha) \phi(x) d x=\int_{0}^{1} \delta(x-\alpha) \phi(x) d x=\phi(\alpha)$$

$\phi(x) \in C^{1}[0,1] \text { vanishing at } x=0 \text { and } x=1, \text { where } \delta_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a continuous nonnegative function with compact support such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_{\epsilon}(x) dx=1$$

Integrating,

$$\int_{\alpha^{-}}^{\alpha^{+}}\left(\tau u_{x}\right)_{x} d x=\int_{\alpha^{-}}^{\alpha^{+}} \delta(x-\alpha) d x=1$$

This leads to $$\tau u_{x}\left(\alpha^{+}\right)=\tau u_{x}\left(\alpha^{-}\right)+1$$.

> My question is, why is the exact solution then given by the following?
>
> $$u(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{-\frac{(1-\alpha) x}{\tau}} & {\text { if } 0 \leq x \leq \alpha} \\ {-\frac{\alpha(1-x)}{\tau}} & {\text { if } \alpha<x \leq 1}\end{array}\right.$$ ?
>
> In particular, I don't see where the solution comes from? It seems we > are just using ftc on both sides of the singular point $\alpha$; however i > don't see where $\alpha$ term on the rhs of $u$ comes from..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just integrate in this case, using $Θ$ to denote the Heaviside function (instead of $u$ for the unit ramp function)
$$
(τu_x)_x=δ(x-α)\implies τu_x(x)=C+\Theta(x-α))\implies τu(x)=Cx+D+\max(0,x-α).
$$
Now adjust the constants to satisfy the boundary conditions, $D=u(0)=0$, $C+(1-α)=u(1)=0$ to find
$$
u(x)=\frac1τ(-(1-α)x+\max(0,x-α))=\frac1τ\max(-(1-α)x,-α(1-x)).
$$

Comment: What is $\Theta$ ?

Comment: The unit ramp function, the letter $u$ was already used in the given ODE.

Comment: Can you point me to a reference ? Thanks